# Trying to get a processname but the First property does not exist

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The line is:

```
foreach (var handle in EnumerateProcessWindowHandles(
        Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer").First().Id))
```

But First does not exist:

> Error  1   'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'First' and no extension method 'First' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the reference

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: And is are the reason: `IEnumerable.First` is one of many **extension method**s by LINQ. Being an extension method, the compiler does not know where the method is defined, unless you add an using directive which points to the right classes.

Comment: @BarbariMichael Add System.Core.dll

Comment: Working just had to change also the target to .net 4 or 4.5